# Microsoft Edge Browser not showing table borders

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge Browser is not showing table borders for our website.

Our site has been using the same HTML/CSS code for years.

The table borders show up correctly in Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, and Firefox browsers.

Here is a sample of a page that is failing in EDGE.
http://www.nycourts.gov/forms/familycourt/general.shtml

The CSS code we are using is:

```
table.forms {
border-color:#999999;
border-width:2px;
border-collapse:collapse;
width:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

th.forms {
padding:5px;
border-color:#999999;
border-width:1px;
background-color:#FF9;
}
td.forms {
padding:5px;
border-color:#999999;
border-width:1px;
background-color:#FFC;
}
```

Comment: You are required to post a complete example here, within your question [mcve], but you are serving XML/XHTML as text/html making your document invalid and in 'quirks mode'. You have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 3):

That's strange and shouldn't happen, but I think I have a solution for you:

Both your table and the cells have CSS rules which contain a `border-width` and a `border-color`, but no `border-style`.

If you add `border-style: solid` to these rules, the borders will also show in Edge.